# ZF2 Dependency Injection onto Controller objects without the Service Locator

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2, service-locator

I have been doing a read up on ZF2 Service Locator component and could say I understand how its being used. I have, however, a question which I think its silly but it wouldn't hurt to ask.

I want to have a namespace inside my Module called Component where I can put generic code in like say FunctionsComponent.php, MailerComponent.php or ExcelComponent.php. This would allow me to do some stuff inside my controllers.

What I would like to tryout is to have an ability to have controllers define the components they are interested to use (see below):

```
class SalesController extends AbstractController
{
  protected $components = ['Excel'];

  //In some action
  public function exportAction()
  {
    $data = ['data to be exported'];
    /**
      $data : data to be exported
      boolean : Whether to force download or save the file in a dedicated location
    */
    $this->Excel->export($data, true);
  }
}
```

The idea is to create a ComponentCollection that perhaps implements the FactoryInterface or ServiceLocatorInterface and then let it check each controller when the MvcEvent has been triggered inside my Module class and have the ComponentCollection inject all the controller component and make them accessible without using the service locator as shown below:

```
$excel = $sm->get('Application\Component\Excel');
```

I am well aware that this may seem like a daunting ask but I feel like the best way to learn a framework among other things is to play around with it and try to do the unimaginable.

Comment: I'm' not entirely sure what you are asking here. The most effective way of injecting the controllers dependencies would be via the service locator (using a factory). Otherwise, the alternative (a DI Container) in Zend would be the `Zend\Di` component. They both solve the same problem - The preference with ZF2 should be using the Service Locator.

Comment: The idea is to use the same tools provided by the framework but differently instead of getting a specific component via a service locator we rather define a components property with an array of components we would like to use in our controller and how those components are made available be done in the background where a developer can go like $ComponentName->functionCall($parameters) as opposed to $component = $sl->get('Namespace\Component\ActualComponent') everytime you want to use the component.

Comment: You should avoid using the service manager *in* your services (including the controller). The 'components' you mention are class *dependencies* meaning they should be injected into the required service (via the service locator or DI) so they are then available as instance properties (i.e. `$this->myService`). Should you then wish to have an *convenience* method such as `$ComponentName->functionCall($parameters)` all you would need to do is implement a `__call()`  magic method and determine if the requested method name matches a defined class property.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `BaseController` somewhere and then extend all your `Controllers` from `BaseController`. Then you can inject your dependencies in your `BaseController` and use anywhere in kids. For example, I am doing this in my `Controller` to set head title:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class BaseController extends AbstractActionController
{

    /**
     * Sets the head title for every page
     *
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setHeadTitle($title)
    {
        $viewHelperManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager');
        // Getting the headTitle helper from the view helper manager
        $headTitleHelper = $viewHelperManager->get('headTitle');

        // Setting a separator string for segments
        $headTitleHelper->setSeparator(' - ');

        // Setting the action, controller, module and site name as title segments
        $siteName = 'Ribbon Cutters';
        $translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
        $title = $translator->translate($title);
        $headTitleHelper->append(ucfirst($title));
        $headTitleHelper->append($siteName);
    }

}
```

Instead of defining methods, you can define properties.

```
public $headTitleHelper
```

and assign it in constructor of `BaseController`

```
$this->headTitleHelper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('headTitle');
```

Now you can use `$this->headTitleHelper` in child controllers.

And then

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Application\Controller\BaseController;

class IndexController extends BaseController
{

    /**
     * Property for setting entity manager of doctrine
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * landing page
     *
     * @return ViewModel
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $this->setHeadTitle('Welcome');  // Welcome - Ribbon Cutters

        $viewModel = new ViewModel();

        return $viewModel;
    }



    /**
     * Sets and gives Doctrine Entity Manager
     *
     * @return Doctrine Entity Manager
     */
    protected function getEntityManager()
    {
        if (null === $this->em) {
            $this->em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        }
        return $this->em;
    }
}
```

I think this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Bilal I think I can cook up something around your solution perhaps more of a plugin object or something. I will let you know of the outcome.... :-)